# Why if the loop starts with 1 to size it returns garbage value but when loop starts from 0 it prints valid answer?

Tags: c, function, for-loop, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sumofelements(int a[],int size)
{
   int i,sum=0;
   for (i=1;i<=size;i++)  
   {
      sum+=a[i];
   }
   return sum;
}

int main()
{
   int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
   int size=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
   int soe=sumofelements(a,size);
   printf("sum of the elements=%d\n",soe);
}
```

The error in the `sumofelements` where the `for` loop if it starts with 1 it produces garbage value.

Comment: Because when you use `for (i = 1; i <= size; i++)`, you're reading out of bounds of the array, invoking undefined behaviour.  The elements available are from`a[0]` to `a[size-1]`.  Don't read out of bounds of an array.  In C, idiomatic loops use `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)`.

Comment: Why would you start by 1? You would omit one element with that, since index counting start by 0 for the first element.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `for` statement.  The sum should be `+= a[i-1];`

Answer (score 5):

This loop:

```
for (i=1;i<=size;i++)  
{
   sum+=a[i];
}
```

uses a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4] and a[5]

This loop:

```
for (i=0;i<size;i++)  
{
   sum+=a[i];
}
```

uses a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3] and a[4]

There is no a[5]. And you forgot a[0]. So the second loop gives you the right answer, and the first loop doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because with the `for` loop condition `i <= size`, you would read beyond the bounds of the array `a` points to, at the last iteration of the loop, which is the reason that the program has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/12139179).

If you would use `i < size` this would be correct,  despite it makes less sense to set `i` to `1` because index counts start at 0 and you would omit one array element with that, which is kind of vital if you count all values of each elements together.

I think your whole confusion is made just because you probably think that the first element would be `a[1]`,  which it is not - it is `a[0]`.

Thus,  the one and only solution to define `sumofelements()` properly is:

```
int sumofelements(int a[],int size)
{
   int i,sum=0;
   for (i=0;i<size;i++)  
   {
       sum+=a[i];
   }

   return sum;
}
```